# Чем Razor Component отличается от произвольного файла, которому сменили расширение на *.razor?

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor

Почему если сменить файлу расширение на *.razor, то VS подсвечивает все красным.

Например, секция @code подсвечивается красным, но если с самого начала все сделать правильно и создать точно такой же файл с таким же содержанием и в том же месте, но Razor Component, то все хорошо.

Visual Studio куда-то дополнительно что-то прописывает? В файле проекта нету никаких упоминаний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм... оказывается Visual Studio не на лету принимает изменения.

Т.е если вкладка была открыта и было выполнено переименование, то анализатор синтаксиса заработает только при переоткрытии файла.